# What strap comes with the EOS 1DX Mark II?

Tags: accessories, camera-straps

What strap comes with the 1DX Mark II?

The manual for the 1DX Mark II only states it comes with a "wide strap" but it does not state which one exactly. (The manual for the 1DX says it comes with a Wide Strap L7)

I think the Wide Strap L5, the Wide Strap L6 and the Wide Strap L7 look similar, but I would like some clarification (maybe from someone who owns a 1DX II).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older L7 strap that was supplied with the EOS 1D X has been replaced with the EW-100DB. They're virtually identical. The version specifically supplied with the EOS 1D X Mark II is the EW-100DB IV.

[image]

The main webbing, which is backed by thin leather, is about 1.5 inches wide and 24 inches long. The tapered leather ends are about 1.5" long. The 3/8" wide connecting straps are about 12" long on either end. Since the end of the connecting straps must be looped back through the supplied buckles, the longest they can be used is about 9.5".

[image: EW-100DB IV]

Versions of the EW-100DB supplied with many other EOS DSLR cameras have the model name included on them, but straps supplied with the 1-series typically do not. Other versions also tend to have a wider red stripe on the edge of the strap, but they are all 1.5" wide.

[image]

Comment: Who doesn't replace the camera-issued strap by something which is more comfortable and practical and doesn't designate you as a target to thieves?

Comment: A LOT of PJs I know had/have the stock straps on all of the camera bodies they own or were/are issued by their employers.

Comment: I asked/answered the question because someone else asked it and then deleted it after a single comment to that question took a cheap pot shot at the OP.